# Delay a java program

Tags: java, swing, delay

Im building a Reversi program and i need to delay the program for something like 0.5 second between each image switch (from black to white, in the Eat function), problem is that using Threads doesnt work, it messes up the variables and i get the wrong outcome. i need some wat to delay the program without using threads. Here is the func in case youll need it.

```
public void func1(int turn)
{
    int i,k;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    for(k=0;k<8;k++)
    {
    if(eat[i][k]==turn)
    {
        board[i][k]=turn;
        if(turn==1)
            squares[i][k].setIcon(new ImageIcon("blkimg.PNG"));
        else
            squares[i][k].setIcon(new ImageIcon("whtimg.PNG"));
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: Java (from the title of the question). I added the tag. :)

Comment: What "messes up" when you use Thread.sleep() ?

Comment: i tried to create another thread, but both of the threads use the same variables so it didnt "fliped" the right pieces

Comment: BTW thanks a lot for the rapid responds, first time in this forum and i really like it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need extensive knowledge of threads to put the current one to sleep using `Thread.sleep()` - I would recommend taking a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: It doesnt "flip" them one by one. for example: if i need to flip 5 pieces, so he waits 5*0.5 seconds and them flip them all together.

Comment: Where did you call sleep? `Thread.sleep(500);` just before `if(turn==1)` should do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: i called it before the "board[i][k]=turn;"

Comment: Sounds like you should take a look at the answer from madth3 - might also want to add the **Swing** tag to your question if this is regarding swing

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be a Swing application (you never say, and this is *very* important information. If so, simply use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to create a delay. Also, don't keep reading in the image files. Read them in only once, create your image icons once, perhaps in a class constructor, and save the ImageIcons to variables or an array or collection.

Comment: thanks, its kind of solved my problem, but an other one appeared. the program doesnt flip all the pieces that it should, only the first one. i places the "ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {" before the "if(turn==1)" and i places the "timer2.stop();
};};
timer2 = new Timer(200, taskPerformer);
timer2.start();" after the " squares[i][k].setIcon(new ImageIcon("whtimg.PNG"));".

Comment: @Sagi: don't try to post code in a comment, since as you can see, it doesn't retain its formatting and becomes unreadable. Instead, edit your original question and add your new code and explanation to the bottom of the original question, and then comment me back so I'll know to look at it. Much luck!

Comment: @Sagi: also, *where* exactly do you want to put the delay? Can you describe in detail just what the method and delay are supposed to do? Assume that I know nothing about your game.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct your is a common problem.

Using `Thread.sleep()` can be causing a delay precisely in the same Thread being used by Swing to change the interface (this usually shown in the interface not reacting and then showing all the changes at once).

You can read more about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) in the Java Tutorials.

A solution could be to use the class SwingWorker and a couple of months ago I created a small sample for a friend. It is [available in GitHub](https://github.com/madth3/Ejemplos-Java/tree/master/SwingSleep). If you don't use Netbeans just take a look at [this class](https://github.com/madth3/Ejemplos-Java/blob/master/SwingSleep/src/madth3/swing/VentanaPrincipal.java) (Lines 90-98 and 151-165).

Edit: Adjustments to reflect the fact that this is just one possible solution. As others have pointed out there is at least another good alternative.

Comment: Better to use a Swing Timer for this simple delay rather than go through all the trouble of a SwingWorker.

Comment: i dont know how to use any of those... it really looks silly that i have to do some much for just a simple 0.5 sec delay.

Comment: @Sagi: there's nothing silly about this as none of us are born with Java knowledge. Please look at the links as they will show you what you need to know to use these tools.

Comment: A `SwingWorker` seems overkill for something that could be achieve using a Swing `Timer`.

Answer (score -1):

Am I missing something? Why can't you just use Thread.sleep() to put the current thread to sleep?

In response to the discussion in the comments:

You need to grasp the idea of the gui thread. If all your code is being executed on the gui thread, the GUI is not being redrawn "as you go".  The quick and dirty fix is to put the necessary calls in to force the redraws as required.

Comment: 1. Im really new at threads and dont really know how to use them, but i did try the sleep func and there was a problem that it didnt "flip" all of the pieces, only the first one.

Comment: Do you have a true multi threading app, or using Thread.sleep() didn't fix your issue? Thread.sleep() doesn't create new threads etc, it just puts the current one to sleep (which is what your questions asks for). Perhaps you are asking the wrong question? Why do you even think you need to delay?

Comment: the delay is very important, if the program flips all the pieces all at once so the user cant really see what move the computer did.

Comment: If this is a Swing or AWT application, Thread.sleep will do nothing more than freeze the application and make it completely unresponsive. Better to use a Swing Timer.